Why did Roman throw some powder into the air?
In Fast X (2023), Tej and Roman were fighting in Bowie’s computer shop. In the heat of the moment,
Tej pulled money from Roman’s shirt and threw it all over. Tej retorted that Roman
had been wanting to engage in a physical fight for years. Roman responded by
standing up and throwing some powder into the air:

Tej: What the hell was that?
Bowie: He's like a ghetto magician.


Why did Roman throw some powder into the air?
